# Node.JS Child_Process Catching Password Prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I use node.js child_process to programatically allow me to supply a password.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('sudo ls');

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

The above throws an error. I am trying to figure out where exactly I can catch where it is wanting the password input and supply that via an environment variable.

I am hoping I can catch when it says `Password` check to make sure its saying that and then pass the password.

Comment: [try one of these packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sudo)

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you're using the spawn command incorrectly.. It should be:

```
const ls = spawn('sudo', ['ls']);
```

Arguments to the child process are specified as the second argument (in an array).

You should then see the prompt for password, and I imagine be able to write to stdin to enter the password (which you're wanting to pass from process.env based on what you've said).

Edit: Quick search on SO seems to suggest it may not be as straight forward as writing to stdin after the prompt..

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out exactly how to catch the exact spot to add the password.